# Return the Matching Type for List or Option

Tags: scala

How do I make `extractValues` to return the right type it contains?

```
trait Ok[T] 
case class OkSingle[U](value: Option[U]) extends Ok[U]
case class OkList[U](value: List[U]) extends Ok[U]

def extractValues[T](o: Ok[T]): Traversable[T] = o match {
  case OkList(l) => l
  case OkSingle(v) => v
}

extractValues(OkSingle(Option(1)))   // 1 
extractValues(OkList(List(1)))       // 2
```

(1) and (2) returns `List(1)`. I want (1) to return `Some(1)`. Perhaps I have to redefine the whole `case class` and `trait` design. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Product` instead of `Traversable[T]` as your return type:

```
def extractValues[T](o: Ok[T]): Product = o match {
```

Since you declared return type to be `Traversable`, Scala compiler uses `Option.option2Iterable` implicit conversion to convert `Option` to `Traversable` that is why you are getting `List(1)` in both the cases.

Trait `Product` is mixed-in both `List` and `Option` so you should get appropriate result.